# Can you identify what is this blue hose under the sink?

Tags: plumbing, kitchen-sink, hose

Please see this image under the sink.  The owner cannot identify what this hose is and it appears to not be connected to anything.  Does anyone know what it is, possibly to an  old garbage disposal that is now gone??

[image: Under_Sink]

[image: Hose_Exit]

Answer (score 3):

I believe it went to provide water to a fridge/ice maker. I had one very similar at my last house. Sometimes they access the water line from under the sink for ease of maintenance. It appears to currently be disconnected though.

Comment: Or, perhaps, for an instant hot water heater or filtered water system at the sink.

Comment: A _what_ heater? :P I wouldn't expect a heater supply to be that small.

Comment: It may also have served a coffee maker.

Comment: Good points. One key is that it routes out behind the sink so it’s going to something elsewhere in the kitchen

Comment: I should have added that this is in a condo.

Comment: A little instant hot water heater, @isherwood. The kind of thing that you put your coffee cup under to get a cup o' hot water for making hot chocolate or other hot beverages. Not something designed for full on washing dishes...

Comment: It would be a supply line to the little tank for the instant hot water heater. Not sure why this one is disappearing behind the wall, however.

Comment: If it connected to a drain on the other hand (such as a port on the grinder), I'd suspect drain from a dishwasher. Where _does_ it connect?

Comment: So, everyone finds it more likely that it’s for an instant hot water heater which is far rarer than a refrigerator which is in nearly every house?